# Is there a way to cancel mongoose find execution and return data from redis instead?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, redis, nestjs

I’m trying to implement Redis cache along with mongoose in nest.js and I'm looking for a way
to check redis cache first before executing find or findOne and return the data from redis
otherwise execute query, save result in redis and return the result.
The reason I'm not implementing [caching](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#caching) as recomended by nest.js
is that I'm also using Apollo Server for GraphQL.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    async getItem(where): Promise<ItemModel> {
        const fromCache = await this.cacheService.getValue('itemId');
        if(!!fromCache){
            return JSON.parse(fromCache);
        } else {
            const response = await this.ItemModel.find(where);
            this.cacheService.setValue('itemId', JSON.stringify(response));
            return response
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to move this piece of code to a single place so that I don't have to
repeat this code for each query in my code since I have multiple services.
I know mongoose middleware has a way to run pre and post functions on queries
but I'm just not sure how to accomplish this using.

These are the versions I'm using:

- nestjs v7
- mongoose v5.10.0

Comment: Please expand on the reason why you're not able to use the default caching setup due to Apollo. I don't see any reason why you couldn't use them together. Interceptors are probably your best bet in terms of native NestJS functionality for implementing this type of pattern in a reusable way

Comment: Default caching as explained in nestjs documentation works at controller level, and what I want to accomplish is cache along with mongoose so that I can clear cache every time a new record is inserted/updated in my mongo database. 

In the documentation states that caching does not work properly with GraphQL 
["In GraphQL applications, interceptors are executed separately for each field resolver. Thus, CacheModule (which uses interceptors to cache responses) will not work properly."]<https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#in-memory-cache>

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [method decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators) where you move the logic to:

```
export const UseCache = (cacheKey:string) => (_target: any, _field: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    // note: important to use non-arrow function here to preserve this-context
    descriptor.value     = async function(...args: any[]) {
        const fromCache = await this.cacheService.getValue(cacheKey);
        if(!!fromCache){
            return JSON.parse(fromCache);
        }
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        await this.cacheService.setValue(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
    };
}
```

Then use it with:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {   

    constructor(private readonly cacheService:CacheService) { .. }

    @UseCache('itemId')
    async getItem(where): Promise<ItemModel> {        
        return this.ItemModel.find(where);
    }

    @UseCache('anotherCacheKey')
    async anotherMethodWithCache(): Promise<any> {        
         // ...            
    }
}
```